# ajax - обработка возвращаемых данных

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Вопрос следующий: как получить значение data, которое передает php сервер js скрипту в текстовом формате (что бы потом сделать проверку, например `if(data == "true")`).

Js:

```
$.post('check.php', {'login':login},
                                function(data) {
                                    if(data == "true"){
                                        //code
                                    }else if(data == "false"){
                                        //code
                                    }
                            });
```

Php:

```
<?php
$login = $_POST['login'];
echo("$login");
?>
```

Comment: а можно немножко больше кода? как передается и куда?

Comment: вы про атрибут data??

Comment: нет, вы не про атрибут data=)

Comment: вы их уже получили - function(data) {; if(data) проверит пусто/не пусто

Comment: Мне нужно не просто проверить пусто/не пусто, а проверить сам текст, который передал сервер (`"true"/"false"`)